# Cast Master - Is there a way to see the current streak?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Theres that nook miles 'achievement' that needs you to have a streak of fish catches.

[image]

But that screen only shows your best streak, or your current streak if you are on that streak.

So if I fail, at like 75, is there a way later on to know at what point my current streak is?

Comment: I'm reluctant to post an answer, as it's hard to say this conclusively until the game has been thoroughly explored or finished, but as far as I can tell, there is no way of seeing the current cast master streak. In game's like these you'd expect some NPC to tell you, for example. Is there any precedence from previous games (this is my first Animal Crossing)?

Comment: @IvoCoumans I’ve played all of the American releases except City Folk and Pocket Camp. While there could be some yearly event I’m missing that requires a streak, the achievement/ reward concept is new, so there’s very little precedent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can only see the current record as you showed. If it stops increasing, you broke the streak.